# Easy proof of a big conjecture based on possibly faulty paper – what to do?

Tags: publications, mathematics, publishability

I’m a mathematician.

I noted that, by combining some results from the literature (all published) and some little effort, one obtains a proof of a big conjecture (at least in the field; it even has a Wikipedia entry). No mistake was found in my arguments yet, after asking some experts in the field.

In my opinion, it is likely that there is a mistake or at least missing details in (exactly) one of the papers I’m using. This paper seems highly complicated, leaving several details to the reader. So what is the best thing to do? Should I make it public (on Arxiv) or even submit to a journal in the hope that a referee takes care of it?

I don’t really care for having a publication from this or something else, but I’m interested where the mistake is or if it might really be a proof (of course it is not unlikely that I made a mistake somewhere).
Another motivation would be to simply make aware that one gets a proof of the conjecture by combining results from the literature and make people want to check those results from the literature again.

Comment: Ask the author of the dubious paper about your doubt. No guarantee that you'll get a reasonable reply, but it's a first step, similarly to how journalists contact everyone involved even if they don't expect to get confessions.

Comment: actually I wanted to stay more annonymous, but too bad I used the same email address for noname and now I can only login with this acc on every stack site... and cant even edit the question.... @darij: Have done that. Author never replied and seems to be inactive.

Comment: Then, I guess, an arXiv preprint isn't a bad idea. Just don't pretend that it's an actual proof, and try to hint as to where you are placing your doubts.

Comment: A mistake is very different than missing details. Can you explain why you suspect there may be a mistake?

Comment: It just feels strange obtaining a proof of a hard conjecture by combining results from the literature, so it is likely that somewhere is a mistake.

Comment: If you think there is likely to be an error in that paper, I suggest looking to see whether you can use its results to prove something even stronger--so strong that you know it's not true.  That's a good method for identifying erroneous methods and results

Comment: Perhaps it works the other way around, too... if the conjecture is true, then the results of this paper are true.  So (if the conjecture really is true) you won't be finding bad consequences of the paper.

Comment: Yes, it is also a problem that one might not be able to really say that the used result of the paper is wrong, since giving a counterexample would also give a counterexample to the big conjecture.

Comment: @Mare _It just feels strange obtaining a proof of a hard conjecture by combining results from the literature_: well, it'd be equally strange for a paper accepted by everyone as correct to have a mistake, and equally strange for a proof of a hard result to follow from published results in the literature (whether correct or not) without anyone noticing this for a long time. All of those things are both strange, and actually not very strange at all. So my opinion is that your proof does not make the possibility of a mistake any more likely than it would be otherwise.

Comment: Perhaps the most likely explanation of all given this story is that it is your proof that has a mistake rather than the paper you use. But you say your proof was checked by experts and seems correct, so that seems to be ruled out as well. At the end of the day, one is left with the optimistic possibility that you might have actually proved a big conjecture. As for what to do, I have some thoughts, I'll try to find time to write and post them as an answer in the next day or two.

Comment: I can also send a copy (it is just 1 page) to interested people. It is algebra (module theory/homological algebra) and the structure of proof should be understandable to any mathematician (although the details require some more deep understanding). I feel bad doing it on arxiv without understanding the quoted papers 100% and of course there is the chance that I made an embarrassing mistake :)

Comment: While it might not be as big a conjecture, it does happen that the answer is basically in the litterature and just needed to be put together. See for example http://mathoverflow.net/questions/137678/non-amenable-groups-with-arbitrarily-large-tarski-number/ (I have also myself written a very short paper where most of the work was already done by others but that was a very minor result).

Answer (score 19):

It seems that you have found an easy one-page proof of a very interesting result along the following lines:

> **Theorem 1.** The results of Papers A, B, C imply Conjecture BIG. Therefore if those papers are correct, then Conjecture BIG is true.

(In the rest of the answer I will assume that your proof is correct since you said it is short and was looked at by experts, but to the extent that you still have doubts, it's obviously advisable to very thoroughly vet the correctness of the proof by going over it yourself and showing it to more people with the relevant expertise.)

Now, normally one would go directly from here to the statement that you've proved Conjecture BIG, but the twist here is that Paper A is complicated and has missing details (hmm, never seen *that* before...) so you are doubting whether it is correct and are reluctant to declare yourself to have proved Conjecture BIG. However, it's worth pointing out that there's already quite some cause for excitement, since you have already proved the very interesting fact that

> **Theorem 2.** Either Paper A is incorrect, or Conjecture BIG is true.

Given that Conjecture BIG is, well, big, and Paper A is a published paper, it seems almost certain that this is already a publishable result, and in any event (even if you don't care about publishing) one that the scientific community will be very interested in. Precisely how exciting it is depends of course on whether you can go even further and figure out which of the two scenarios applies, and if so, what you discover, and, in the event that you discover that it is the first scenario (Paper A is incorrect), whether you are able to correct the results of the paper by completing the missing details or by correcting whatever errors it contains.

---

Now let's discuss what you should do. I see three main options for how to proceed:

1. You can write up Theorem 2 and its easy proof (along with an explanation of why you are formulating it in such a way rather than simply saying you've proved Conjecture BIG), put it on the arXiv, then submit it to a journal, and let others take it from there.
2. You can wait before publishing your findings and first of all spend time studying Paper A so that you understand it well enough to determine whether it is correct. While doing so you will also attempt to fill in any missing details. Once you have determined whether the paper is correct, and (if it's not correct) either managed to correct it (by filling in the gaps and/or correcting erroneous reasoning) or failed to correct it, or convinced yourself (e.g. by finding a counterexample) that its results, not just its proofs, are actually false, you will then be in a position to write a paper that contains a proof of one of the following results:

   - > **Theorem 2** (same formulation as above - in the event that your study of Paper A didn't lead you to any meaningful conclusion)
   - > **Theorem 3.** One of the results of Paper A is false (because its proof is incorrect, and you have proved that the result is also incorrect).
   - > **Theorem 3'.** Conjecture BIG is true (because you have ascertained that Paper A is correct and your initial doubts were misplaced).
   - > **Theorem 3''.** Conjecture BIG is true (because Paper A is essentially correct, but has some missing details you've managed to fill in).
   - > **Theorem 3'''.** Conjecture BIG is true (because the result of Paper A is correct, although the proof in the original paper has an error in it, which you have managed to correct).
3. A variant of option 2 above is to recruit professional help in studying Paper A, either privately by approaching someone you know who may be interested in becoming a collaborator, or publicly, for example by posting your thoughts on the paper on MathOverflow.

As for which of these options is the best one, that depends on how difficult it would be for you to try to pursue options 2 and 3, and whether you want to maximize the amount of fame/glory/credit you get from this discovery. The point is that each of Theorems 3, 3', 3'', and 3''' would be a stronger and more interesting result than theorem 2, so if you prove them your discovery would make a bigger splash, and conversely, if you leave them for someone else you are giving up a potentially very useful opportunity for professional credit and possibly (if this interests you) career advancement.

Thus, if you want to publicize your discovery with the least amount of effort and in the least amount of time and don't care about maximizing the credit you get from it, you should pursue option 1. If you are willing to take the time and trouble to look more in depth into Paper A, you should pursue options 2 or 3, with option 3 being a better approach if Paper A is technically too complicated for you to study by yourself. One additional concern in that case is the issue of priority, so if you are worried that someone else may discover your one-page proof while you are busy studying Paper A, you should make sure to document your discovery including relevant dates, show it to a few trusted people, and limit the time you are working on this to a reasonable amount of time (say, no more than 3–6 months).

I should add finally that you have no ethical obligation to determine whether the results of Paper A are correct (emailing the author to ask them their thoughts is certainly a nice thing to do, but you said in the comments that you tried that already and it hasn't led you anywhere). So from an ethical point of view, any of the options I outlined above is completely acceptable.

Comment: Thank you for this very mathematical answer. I think I will wait a bit and then go for option 1 after checking everything again.

Comment: Maybe one more questions: How to judge to which journal one can possible send a paper with the result of theorem 2? (real) proof of conjecture big would be suitable for any journal but just theorem 2 might be strange for any journal.

Comment: @Mare I agree that it is a strange formulation for a theorem, and when you write the paper you should put careful thought into how to formulate things precisely to make it seem more natural (maybe not even using the heading "theorem" - I used that mainly for the sake of readability of my answer). I don't feel I can advise you on how to optimize all those details or how to choose the journal given that I have no knowledge of the area or precise results you are dealing with. My only suggestion is to consult an experienced mathematician who is familiar with the details of what you're working on